# How to add elements to a matrix from another matrix given at its indices efficiently in JAX?

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I am trying to create a binned sum of elements of a matrix such that the elements belonging to each bin are summed together.

In terms of python, I have three matrices: one 1d array containing the values I want to add which I call **values**, a 2D array containing the indices in which the nth value of the values matrix needs to be added which I call **index_mat** and a zeros 2D matrix to which I want to add the values to, which I call **sol**.

In terms of Pythton, an example of what I want to do using for loops is:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

values = np.random.random((1000,2)) * 100

bins = jnp.linspace(0,100,1000)
indices = jnp.digitize(values, bins)

sol = jnp.zeros((len(bins), len(bins), 2))

for i in range(len(indices)):
   sol = sol.at[indices[i][0],indices[i][1]].add(values[i])
```

What I would like to find is an optimal way of implementing within the JAX framework the sum of elements that can be done in this non-optimal manner.

In general, I intend to extend this to more dimensions than (1000, 1000, 2) and I would like to find a faster solution that hopefully requires not of a for loop.

Comment: @Robert I am sorry. I think they got edited out by commenter , not sure where they come from

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the same thing more efficiently via broadcasted index update:

```py
sol = jnp.zeros((len(bins), len(bins), 2))
sol = sol.at[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]].add(values)
```

Comment: Thanks as this solution is fully working. May ask: If the third dimension of sol was not a fixed float but a number given by the shape of values (that in general may change), would there be a way to generalise this?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. I’d suggest creating a new post with an example of what you’re trying to do.